# fabric8 API: How do I use a Kubernetes ConfigMap with subPath?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, fabric8

**Summary**: Is there an example of using an already in existence [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap) with a `subPath` option using the Fabric8 APIs? By `subPath` I mean the K8s configuration (normally expressed in YAML) to inject a single file into a container.

**Details**:

I'm attempting to extend the [Jenkins Kubernetes Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) because we need it to support the K8s  ConfigMap's `subPath` facility in order to make a file accessible under /etc without then masking the whole of /etc. That plugin uses Fabric8's API in its [ConfigMapVolume.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes/ConfigMapVolume.java) file.

What I'm having trouble with are examples demonstrating using K8s ConfigMap with a `subPath`. Or even finding confirmation that this is supported at all. Any hints to examples or documentation I have missed will be much appreciated.

For reference, an example YAML deployment file that uses `subPath` is shown below and it references a config map called "resolver-config":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /etc/resolv.conf
      subPath: resolv.conf
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: resolver-config
```

Comment: It works when it works. :-) I don't know to what degree is affects Kubernetes alone, but there apparently can be issues with using ``subPath`` with ``configmap`` mounting when used under OpenShift due to SELinux issues. https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/16951 That does reference an upstream Kubernetes issue about it, which in turns links to other issues.